# Xcode10.3 - Xib can't drag & drop UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode10.3

`Xcode Version` : `10.3`

I used xib to create a `UIView` and added a `UICollectionView` to the `UIView`.

When I added `UICollectionViewCell`, it didn't work. Means I can't drag `UICollectionViewCell` into `UICollectionView`

The structure I want is like this

```
UIView(xib) -> UICollectionView(xib) -> UICollectionViewCell(xib)
```

Of course, I can add `UICollectionViewCell` with code, but why doesn't it work with xib? Does anyone know the reason?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Only with Storyboards.

Comment: @Larme You mean I can only use drag and drop `UICollectionViewCell` in `Storyboard`.

Comment: @Larme As you said, I found this problem in my development, so is this a `Xib` bug?

Comment: Can't find a doc about it, but it might exist. It's not a bug, it's always been like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add prototype cells in `UICollectionView` in xib and then change it's class from `UICollectionViewCell` to your desired custom class.

Comment: yes, add prototype cells not work with xib，I mean I can't drag `UICollectionViewCell` into `UICollectionView`

Comment: It works. In your xib. select your collectionView and then increase the items count from 0 to 1 and change your prototype cell class.

Answer (score 0):

@Nullable for your reference please check this gif [image: demo gif to add custom cell in collection view inside xib]

Comment: Thank you, you are really attentive. My creation steps are like this: `cmd + n` -> `User interface` Select `View` -> Drag and drop `UICollectionView` -> Drag and drop `UICollectionViewCell ` failed. There is no `items` you mentioned, but it is working in `Storyboard`

Comment: It is not possible for `View` xibs. Like in the gif above, I've added this in `UICollectionView` inside `CollectionCell` xib and then it's `items` property was available for prototyping cells.